# How to tag in SQL based on hierarchy?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need a SQL query to classify users based on their color based on a hierarchy.

[image]

Each user has a few different colors they can be tagged as. The SQL query I want is to tag users as such:

1. If they have 1 color tagged as GREEN, tag the whole user as green.
2. If they dont have 1 color tagged as green, then take the next one: BLUE.
3. If they dont have 1 color tagged as green or blue, then take the next one: RED.

User 1 in this case would be tagged as GREEN.
User 2 would be tagged as BLUE.
User 3 would be tagged as BLUE.
User would be tagged as GREEN.

Iève been trying with a case statement but I am not getting what I need. Any tips?

Comment: Some code would be nice of what you tried ... but in theory you should be able to give a numeric value to the color and then then use `max` to get what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ARRAY_AGG sorted by specific rules

```
SELECT *,
 (ARRAY_AGG(COLOR) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DECODE(COLOR,'Green',1,'Blue',2,'Red',3))
  OVER(PARTITION BY USER))[0]::STRING AS color_group
FROM tab;
```

---

Using [MIN_BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by) function:

```
SELECT *, 
  MIN_BY(COLOR,DECODE(COLOR,'GREEN',1,'BLUE',2,'RED',3)) OVER(PARTITION BY USER) 
FROM tab;
```

Sample input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(USER INT, COLOR TEXT)
AS
SELECT 1, 'BLUE'  UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'BLUE'  UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'GREEN' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'RED'   UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 'BLUE'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 'BLUE'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 'BLUE'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 'BLUE'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 'BLUE'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 'GREEN' UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 'RED';
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Using the MIN_BY function gave me exactly what I was looking for! thank you